# c++ header file errors?

Tags: visual-c++

(Visual Studio c++ 6.0)

```
.\app.h(69) : error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'IsProcessRunning'
.\app.h(69) : error C2501: 'DWORD' : missing storage-class or type specifiers
.\app.h(69) : error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'LPCTSTR'
.\app.h(70) : error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'LPCTSTR'
```

Not sure why these errors?  Why the syntax error?  DWORD and LPCTSRT are recognized.

```
    virtual BOOLEAN DoNew( void );

    DWORD IsProcessRunning(LPCTSTR procname);
    bool TerminateProcess(LPCTSTR procname);

    void UpdateControllerStatus( void );
```

Comment: You've forgotten to include a definition for DWORD and LPCTSTR; probably missing #include <windows.h>

Comment: It is in the cpp but when I include windows.h in the this header file than there are 1000 more errors within Windows own header files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the errors, DWORD is not recognized. Are you sure you are including windows.h?

Answer (score -1):

Add #include  to the beginning of your code...